# Is content scraping useful for SEO or harmful?

Tags: duplicate-content, content, negative-seo

Is content scraping useful for SEO or harmful?
 Scraping: Taking content from other places on the web and publishing it on your own site.
There are many websites that only contain pieces of other websites or stolen content. Many sites will take articles from other websites and publish them as if they were their own, or will copy entire websites.Will this process is useful for SEO rankings.

Comment: BTW- Panda 4.1 was just released around November 23-25 2014 and quite possibly earlier. If the drop is around/between the 20th - 25th, then it could be Panda 4.1. Panda 4.0 and 4.1 addresses this issue specifically.

Comment: @closetnoc Panda 4.1 was released just around November 23-25 2014 or September 23-25 2014? Because today only November 23 that's why got confused.

Comment: @SathiyaKumar The first site I saw said November or my mind went wonky- not sure which, but I think November is wrong and I reported it wrong. Good catch!! Ironically, I got it right in another answer.

Answer (score 8):

Content Scraping is not at all Good and it is a worst SEO technique (Negative SEO) which will surely harm your website in Panda update. Google will penalize those websites which are following content scraping technique.

In [Google support page](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/2721312?hl=en) you can find

> Scraped content
>
> Some webmasters use content taken (“scraped”) from other, more
>   reputable sites on the assumption that increasing the volume of pages
>   on their site is a good long-term strategy regardless of the relevance
>   or uniqueness of that content. Purely scraped content, even from
>   high-quality sources, may not provide any added value to your users
>   without additional useful services or content provided by your site;
>   it may also constitute copyright infringement in some cases. It's
>   worthwhile to take the time to create original content that sets your
>   site apart. This will keep your visitors coming back and will provide
>   more useful results for users searching on Google.
>
> Some examples of scraping include:
>
> - Sites that copy and republish content from other sites without adding    any original content or value
> - Sites that copy content from other sites, modify it slightly (for    example, by substituting synonyms or using automated techniques), and 
>     republish it
> - Sites that reproduce content feeds from other sites without providing    some type of unique organization or benefit to the user
> - Sites dedicated to embedding content such as video, images, or other    media from other sites without substantial added value to the
>     user

Matt Cutts, Google’s head of search spam announced a new tool to let Google know when you find scraped content ranking better than original content and he stated that

> If you see a scraper URL outranking the original source of content in
>   Google, please tell us about it: http://t.co/WohXQmI45X

Answer (score 1):

It's worth mentioning that Panda, a Google algorithm update, deals with this specifically. Sites with large swathes of duplicate content or pages with very little content are penalized quite heavily - the idea is to prevent people who's sole purpose is the ranking of keywords. Each page either has to have a good portion of good, unique content or you need ensure that it is kept out of Google's index, by using meta robots tag (noindex, follow) or by preventing crawling using *robots.txt*

Answer (score 0):

Content scraping is always worst techniques in SEO. If you working on content scraping, please come out from this method. surely this kind of content scrapped websites will get penalty from Google.

Comment: "swapping" or "scraping"?    Can you improve this answer by adding references for your reasoning or explain why this is true from your personal experience?

Answer (score 0):

Collecting the content from multiple sources it is good to learn new things but it is a NEGATIVE for SEO

Because Google have one algorithm that algorithm is called as a Panda algorithm so if you copied content from other website Google may identify your website and hit with the panda update

if it happen to your website rank is going down day by day...

so my solutions is don't go for content scraping...